# Why exactly is this injective? Algebraic Topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $(A^*, d^i)$ be a chain complex of finite dimensional vector spaces, i.e, 
>   $$0 \to A^0 \to A^1 \to \dots \to A^n \to 0.$$ Show the sequence $$0 \to H^i(A^*) \to A^i/Im(d^{i-1}) \to Im(d^i) \to 0$$
>   is exact. Here $H^i(A^*)$ denotes the $i$th cohomology group of $A^*$, that is we are required to show that $$0 \to \frac{Ker d^i}{Im (d^{i-1})} \to \frac{A^i}{Im (d^{i-1})} \to Im(d^i) \to 0 $$ is exact (for each $i$, but we show for a general $i$).

Can someone tell me why must the map $\frac{Ker d^i}{Im (d^{i-1})} \to \frac{A^i}{Im (d^{i-1})}$ be the inclusion map? We weren't told anything about the map $H^i(A^*) \to A^i/Im(d^{i-1})$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the question

Comment: @Clayton, the question should read "show it is exact", the first part is not given for free.

Comment: @anomaly, of the two quotient spaces I have? I don't think it will help here.

Comment: My apologies, I assumed you had proven the sequence was exact and was just asking why it must be the inclusion.

Comment: @Clayton, no it is fine. It was me who made the mistake after all.

Comment: Actually could you remind me again why it is true if we are told that the first chain complex is exact?

Comment: Let's forget about chain complexes for a moment. If you have a subspace $V' \subset V$ then subspaces of the quotient $V/V'$ correspond to subspaces of $V$ that contain $V'$ and this correspondence preserves inclusion.

Comment: @Hoot, so you are saying if $T : V' \to V/V'$, then $T(x + V') = x + V'$…?

Comment: I guess I would write $T\colon V \to V/V'$ for the projection, and then the correspondence just comes from the map: I send $W$ with $V' \subset W \subset V$ to $T(W)$ and $J \subset V/V'$ to $T^{-1}(J)$. And I should also say that $T(W) = W/V'$.

Comment: Aw man, this is getting confusing with all these new objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your question has anything to do with topology. This is just a linear algebra question.

You have inclusion map $\ker(d^i)\to A^i$. Compose it with the projection $A^i\to A^i/Im(d^{i-1})$. By definition, the kernel of the resulting map is $\ker(d^i)\cap Im(d^{i-1})$.

But since $d^id^{i-1}=0$, you know that $Im(d^{i-1})\subset \ker(d^i)$, and so the intersection $\ker(d^i)\cap Im(d^{i-1})$ is just $Im(d^{i-1})$. Therefore, the kernel of the map $\ker(d^i)\to A^i\to A^i/Im(d^{i-1})$ is exactly $Im(d^{i-1})$. Then you can use the first isomorphism theorem to say that $\ker(d^i)/Im(d^{i-1})\to A^i/Im(d^{i-1})$ is isomorphism on its image, and therefore injective.

Comment: Sorry my linear algebra is quite weak. Why must $ker(d^i) \to A^i$ be an inclusion? $$Ker(d^i) = \{ x : d^i x = 0 \}$$. Why can't there be a noninjective map from $Ker(d^i) \to A^i$?

Comment: Of course the *can* be a non-injective map $Ker(d^i) \to A^i$. But in your case the map $Ker(d^i) \to A^i$ you are considering is by definition just the obvious inclusion.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't see why $ker(d^i) \to A^i$ be obviously the inclusion because as you said there are other possible noninjective maps. Why are we given the freedom to choose the inclusion on $ker(d^i) \to A^I$?

Comment: Where did you get the map from the third formula in your question from? *By definition* of this map it comes from the natural inclusion $ker(d^i) \to A^i$.

Comment: I just thought that $H^i(A^*) = \frac{Ker(d^i)}{Im(d^{i-1})}$, and $A^*$ was just a compact way of writing the third formula. So it was just symbolic speculation, no math...

Comment: In your third line you said "show **the** sequence is exact". This "the" indicates you know the terms of the sequence and the maps between them. So what are the maps? How do you get the sequence? Do you understand where the sequence came from?

Comment: Well, I know that the map between $A^i/Im(d^{i-1}) \to Im(d^i)$ is just $d^i$, but it is not told what the map $H^i(A^*) \to A^i/Im(d^{i-1})$ is.

Comment: I repeat one of my previous comments. *By definition* of this map it comes from the natural inclusion $ker(d^i) \to A^i$. It is *by definition*. Otherwise it doesn't even make sense to talk about **the** exact sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Showing that a potentially short exact sequence is exact without knowing what the maps are is a fruitless endeavor. If the writer did not explicitly give the maps, its likely they just meant the most obvious ones (in this case where the first map is the map induced from the inclusion and the second map is induced from $d^i$).